# How can I change a Preference when WearableListView snaps to new list item?

Tags: android, android-listview, wear-os

I've implemented a `WearableListView` in order to allow the user to choose a preference in my app.  Currently, whenever the user clicks on an item, I save that item's tag in a preference.  This code lives in the `onClick` method of the class implementing `WearableListView.onClick`

I've also noticed that when I change the item selected in the list (the item in center screen)
that persists upon leaving and coming back to this list.  So I'm wondering how can I access that offset value? Or what method is called in order to make your current item persist once you leave and come back to a list? I would like the user to not need to click on the list item, but simply scroll away and that item tag save.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot test it right now, but please take a look at `WearableListView.OnScrollListener` class.

There is a promising-looking method called `onCentralPositionChanged(int centralPosition)`. Just add it via `addOnScrollListener(WearableListView.OnScrollListener listener)` method and update your preferences in `onCentralPositionChanged` callback:

```
public void onCentralPositionChanged(int centralPosition) {
    // update your preferences according to centralPosition
}
```