# Get position of WearableListView

Tags: android, listview, position, wear-os

I need your help!

I have three WearableListViews side by side, filled with the values from 0-9.
The idea is that you can scroll the three different lists to create fast and simple a number between 000 and 999.

Now I need the selected values, but no method I tried get me the right values.

There were:

- getScrollX(),
- getScrollY(),
- getScrollState(),
- ...

If you perform a click on an item within the list, you can get the position with viewHolder.getPosition(); in the onClick-method.

Does anybody know, how to get the current position scrolled to of all three WearableListView simultaneously?

Comment: http://www.technotalkative.com/android-wear-part-5-wearablelistview/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the answer in [How can I change a Preference when WearableListView snaps to new list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004112)

basically add a `WearableListView.OnScrollListener` to your WearableListViews and implement

```
onCentralPositionChanged(int centralPosition);
```

this will do the trick.

Comment: Just a small pitfall, use: addOnScrollListener() and not setOnScrollListener() which is inherited from RecyclerView and expects a different interface.